# mongoose.find() returns undefined

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

[MongoDB ] I'm trying to get object `name` from all documents in collection. But `console.log(users.name)` returns undefined.

```js
Data.find({}, 'name', function (err, users) {
    if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    } else {
    console.log(users.name)
    }
})
```

However if I try to log `users.length` it works fine. Only `users.name` returns undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter must be an object not just a single string. And also `.find` returns array, not an object so either iterate over the array or do `console.log(users[0].name)`

```
Data.find({}, { name: 1 }, function (err, users) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(users.name);
  }
});
```